# How to get pull_number for specific pull request Github v3?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to write an automated PR merger. pull_number is an important bit to perform the action according to Github API v3.
Can anyone guide me on how to get this pull_request number for automerging?
If you already have any code for it, please direct me to that as well.
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request

Comment: What data do you have?  That's the pull request number, the same one you see in the interface.  Are you trying to do that based on the branch?  Are you trying to merge all pull requests and want to iterate over all of them?

Comment: I am trying to merge specific pull requests. Now i need pull_number of those pull requests.

Comment: What should the PR merge be triggered from?

Comment: It is just a wrapper on top of the API. Finally doing API call.

Comment: Yes, but what should be the trigger to call your wrapper?

Comment: That logic I will not like to disclose. Anyways, I have found the pull_number hidden in the create and list PR API calls. Posted as an answer. Thanks to both @bk2204 and Madhu

Answer (score 0):

The pull_number as pointed out is in the struct returned while creating a PR or list a PR.

It is struct.number to be specific in the responses.

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests